How to send data in form with AJAX and return old values and error messages if validation failed on Laravel 10
The project I'm working on now is about the collection of achievement information and reward information. Each achievement can have neither no reward nor have more than one reward information. I created functions in blade file where the JavaScript is used to add or remove reward items. When I dd the data I send from $request in the controller.
This is what the data look like:
  "achievement_name" => "Research on the factors affecting root growth in leguminous plants"
  "achievement_type_id" => "1"
  "start_achievement_date" => "2024-10-01"
  "finish_achievement_date" => null
  "start_achievement_education_level_id" => "1"
  "start_achievement_academic_year" => "2024"
  "start_achievement_academic_semester" => "1"
  "finish_achievement_education_level_id" => "1"
  "finish_achievement_academic_year" => "2024"
  "finish_achievement_academic_semester" => "2"
  "reward" => array:2 [▶]
        ["1":
              [
                    "reward_award_status":"1",
                    "reward_type_id":"1",
                    "reward_owner_name":"International Kid Scientist Programme",
                    "reward_owner_description":"Example of Description",
                    "reward_date":"2024-10-04",
                    "reward_name":"International Kid Scientist",
                    "reward_education_level_id":"1",
                    "reward_academic_year":"2024",
                    "reward_academic_semester":"1",
                    "reward_prize_amount":null
              ],
        ["2":
              [
                    "reward_award_status":"1",
                    "reward_type_id":"3",
                    "reward_owner_name":"National Kid Scientist Programme",
                    "reward_owner_description":"Example of Description",
                    "reward_date":"2024-10-04",
                    "reward_name":"National Kid Scientist",
                    "reward_education_level_id":"1",
                    "reward_academic_year":"2024",
                    "reward_academic_semester":"1",
                    "reward_prize_amount":null
            ],
        ]
  "reward_total_items" => "2"

After the validation in the controller failed, I set the $data as an array of all old values,  all error messages and the message for the SweetAlert pop-up with this code :
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $data = array();

    $old_values = $request->all();
    $all_errors = $validator->errors();
    $message = 'Sorry!\nPlease fill your form properly!';

    $data = compact(
        'message',
        'old_values',
        'all_errors',
    );

    return $data; 
}

This is the form tag I used with @csrf :
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('achievement_info.store_achievement_info', ['profile_id' => $student->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

This is the route I set:
Route::post('/menu_student/{profile_id}/store_achievement_info', [AchievementInfoController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth')->name('achievement_info.store_achievement_info');

This is the part of JavaScript:
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Manage Form
        let form = $('#form');
        
        form.submit(function (e){

            var form_data = new FormData(this);
            console.log("Form Data : " + form_data);

            // Prevent Any Action(s)
            e.preventDefault();

            // Send Data using AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                // data: form.serialize(),
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                error: function(data){

                    // console.log(data.responseJSON);

                    let status = data.status;
                    console.log("Status : " + status);

                    // Get Message
                    let message = data.message;

                    // alert("Message : " + message);

                    // Show Alert Message
                    Swal.fire({
                        position: 'center',
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: message,
                        showCloseButton: false,
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })

                    // Get All Error(s)
                    let errors = data.all_errors;

                    // Show Each Error
                    // For Achievement + Reward Information
                    $.each(errors, function(key, message){

                        // Replace '.' from Reward Information Field(s)
                        let elementID = key.replace(/\./g, '_');
                        let element = $('#' + elementID);

                        // Add 'is-invalid' Class
                        element.addClass('is-invalid');

                        // Append Error Message After Element
                        element.after('<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>' + message[0] + '</strong></span>');
                    });

                    // Get All Old Value(s)
                    let old_values = data.old_values;
                    
                    // Re-populate Form Fields with Old Value(s)
                    // For Achievement
                    $('#achievement_name').val(old_values.achievement_name);
                    $('#start_achievement_date').val(old_values.start_achievement_date);
                    $('#finish_achievement_date').val(old_values.finish_achievement_date);
                    $('#start_achievement_education_level_id').val(old_values.start_achievement_education_level_id).change();
                    $('#start_achievement_academic_year').val(old_values.start_achievement_academic_year);
                    $('#start_achievement_academic_semester').val(old_values.start_achievement_academic_semester);
                    $('#finish_achievement_education_level_id').val(old_values.finish_achievement_education_level_id).change();
                    $('#finish_achievement_academic_year').val(old_values.finish_achievement_academic_year);
                    $('#finish_achievement_academic_semester').val(old_values.finish_achievement_academic_semester);
                    
                    // For Reward Total Items 
                    $('#reward_total_items').val(old_values.reward_total_items);

                    // Re-populate Form Fields with Old Value(s)
                    // For Reward Information
                    $.each(old_values.reward, function(key, value){
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_award_status').val(value.reward_award_status);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_type_id').val(value.reward_type_id).change();
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_name').val(value.reward_owner_name);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_description').val(value.reward_owner_description);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_date').val(value.reward_date);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_name').val(value.reward_name);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_education_level_id').val(old_values.reward_education_level_id).change();
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_academic_year').val(old_values.reward_academic_year);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_academic_semester').val(old_values.reward_academic_semester);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_prize_amount').val(old_values.reward_prize_amount);
                        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_currency_id').val(old_values.reward_currency_id).change();
                    });
                },
                success: function(response){
                
                    // Go to Student Profile Page
                    window.location.replace(response.route);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

After submitting the form and the validations have failed, I cannot return to the previous page.
I'm facing the white screen with this data in JSON:
{"message":"Sorry!\\nPlease fill your form properly!","old_values":{"_token":"iCSqEWqriuvxs32jS3pWrlime7tkwLyCHYuVWxfE","achievement_name":"Research on the factors affecting root growth in leguminous plants","achievement_type_id":"1","start_achievement_date":"2024-10-01","finish_achievement_date":null,"start_achievement_education_level_id":"1","start_achievement_academic_year":"2024","start_achievement_academic_semester":"1","finish_achievement_education_level_id":"1","finish_achievement_academic_year":"2024","finish_achievement_academic_semester":"2","reward":{"1":{"reward_award_status":"1","reward_type_id":"1","reward_owner_name":null,"reward_owner_description":null,"reward_date":null,"reward_name":null,"reward_academic_year":null,"reward_academic_semester":null,"reward_prize_amount":null}},"reward_total_items":"1"},"all_errors":{"finish_achievement_date":["Please specify the finish date of the achievement"],"reward.1.reward_date":["Please specify the date you received the award"],"reward.1.reward_name":["Please specify reward name"],"reward.1.reward_owner_name":["Please fill the program name you are participated"],"reward.1.reward_owner_description":["Please fill information about the program you are participated"]}...}

If you guys have any ideas to fix this out.
